# Refactoring Assistance

Tags: java

I am attempting to refactor this class and being quite new to java, I'm terrified of breaking it. I mean it already works but I'm trying to refine it. The main issues I'm looking at is dealing with the repition of command size in the code and I was looking at making a hashmap for the colours but I don't believe that would shorten the code. I have already began extracting methods from the code i.e. help() used to be in the switch case but I've pulled it out to make things more clearer. I'm trying to follow in that vein.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DrawingTool {
    Color color;
    // The drawing pen.
    HashMap<String, Pen> pcase = new HashMap<String, Pen>();
    // Where to draw.
    private Canvas canvas;
    // Source of user commands.
    private InputReader reader;
    private Pen pen;

    /**
     * Prepare to draw on a canvas of default size.
     * The pen starts up at position (0, 0) and its
     * colour is black.
     */
    public DrawingTool() {
        this(500, 400);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare to draw on a canvas of specified size.
     * The pen starts up at position (0, 0) and its
     * colour is black.
     *
     * @param width  The canvas width.
     * @param height The canvas height.
     */
    public DrawingTool(int width, int height) {
        canvas = new Canvas("Drawing Program", width, height);
        reader = new InputReader();
    }

    private void noPen() {
        if (pcase.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Pen name not recognized.");
        }
    }

    public void printHelp() {
        System.out.println("The available commands are:         move,     movetto, turn,    turnto and colour.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(
                "Please not that commands like 'move' and 'turn'should be followed by an integer i.e.(move 10).");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(
                "Similarly, commands such as moveto and turnto must be followed by two integers, the first being for the horizontal");
        System.out.println("positioning and the second to the vertical. i.e.(moveto 10 20).");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The available colours are: red, blue, yellow, magenta, green and black.");
        System.out.println("To choose a colour, simply type 'colour' followed by any of the aforementioned colours.");
    }

    /**
     * Allow the user to draw on the canvas by typing commands.
     */
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the drawing tool.");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Type bye to exit.");

        boolean finished = false;

        int distance = 0;

        int xPosition = 0;

        int yPosition = 0;

        int angle = 0;

        int degrees = 0;


        String name;

        while (!finished) {
            LinkedList<String> command = reader.getInput();
            if (!command.isEmpty()) {
                String firstWord = command.get(0);
                if (firstWord.equals("move")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (reader.isAnInteger(secondWord)) {
                            distance = reader.convertToInteger(secondWord);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("moveto")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 3) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (reader.isAnInteger(secondWord)) {
                            xPosition = reader.convertToInteger(secondWord);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Unrecognised command:" + distance);
                    }
                    if (command.size() >= 3) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        String thirdWord = command.get(2);
                        if (reader.isAnInteger(secondWord) || reader.isAnInteger(thirdWord)) {
                            xPosition = reader.convertToInteger(secondWord);
                            yPosition = reader.convertToInteger(thirdWord);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Unrecognised command:" + xPosition);
                        System.out.println("Unrecognised command:" + yPosition);
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("turn")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (reader.isAnInteger(secondWord)) {
                            degrees = reader.convertToInteger(secondWord);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Unrecognised command:" + degrees);
                        ;
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("turnto")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (reader.isAnInteger(secondWord)) {
                            angle = reader.convertToInteger(secondWord);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Unrecognised command:" + angle);
                        ;
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("colour")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (secondWord.equals("red")) {
                            color = Color.red;
                            pen.setColor(color);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("colour")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (secondWord.equals("blue")) {
                            color = Color.blue;
                            pen.setColor(color);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("colour")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (secondWord.equals("yellow")) {
                            color = Color.yellow;
                            pen.setColor(color);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("colour")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (secondWord.equals("magenta")) {
                            color = Color.magenta;
                            pen.setColor(color);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("colour")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (secondWord.equals("green")) {
                            color = Color.green;
                            pen.setColor(color);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                if (firstWord.equals("colour")) {
                    if (command.size() >= 2) {
                        String secondWord = command.get(1);
                        if (secondWord.equals("black")) {
                            color = Color.black;
                            pen.setColor(color);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Second word missing");
                    }
                }
                switch (firstWord) {
                    case "bye":
                        finished = true;
                        break;

                    case "check":
                        pen.isPenDown();
                        System.out.println("The pen is " + (pen.isPenDown() ? "down" : "up") + ".");
                        break;

                    case "down":
                        pen.penDown();
                        break;

                    case "up":
                        pen.penUp();
                        break;

                    case "move":
                        pen.move(distance);
                        break;

                    case "moveto":
                        pen.moveTo(xPosition, yPosition);
                        break;

                    case "turn":
                        pen.turn(degrees);
                        break;

                    case "turnto":
                        pen.turnTo(angle);
                        break;

                    case "colour":
                        pen.setColor(color);
                        break;

                    case "pen":
                        if (firstWord.equals("pen")) {
                            String secondWord = command.get(1);
                            if (command.size() >= 2) {
                                pcase.put(secondWord, new Pen(0, 0, canvas));
                                pen = pcase.get(secondWord);
                            }
                            else {
                                noPen();
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case "select":
                        if (firstWord.equals("select")) {
                            String secondWord = command.get(1);
                            if (command.size() >= 2) {
                                pen = pcase.get(secondWord);

                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Second word missing");
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case "delete":
                        if (firstWord.equals("delete")) {
                            String secondWord = command.get(1);
                            if (command.size() >= 2) {
                                pcase.remove(secondWord);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Second word missing");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "help":
                        printHelp();
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Unrecognised command: " + firstWord);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }
}
```

Comment: _"It already works but I'm trying to refine it"_. It sounds like this post belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, the `Working Effectively with Legacy Code` book sounds like it'd be perfect for you.

Answer (score 2):

The *only* way of solving this is to

1. Acquire any specifications and documentation that was used to produce the code.
2. Speak to the authors of the code, and any users, if available.
3. Build a comprehensive set of unit tests centred around the code. Aim for 100% code coverage.
4. Make the changes one by one, making sure you don't break any of the tests.
5. Retain the unit tests - they are always useful.

For step (3), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit